# Key derivation function library for both Swift and Kotlin?

Tags: android, ios, swift, kotlin, encryption

I’m working on giving my app users the ability to sync their data with the cloud. However I plan on doing this securely by encrypting their data. My plan is to do the following according to the accepted answer on stack exchange:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/157422/store-encrypted-user-data-in-database

1. use a key derivation function to convert the user's password into an encryption key
2. use a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator to generate a separate key that would encrypt the user's data
3. use the derived key to encrypt the generated key
4. The resulting ciphertext of the data encryption key could then be stored safely in the user table of your database

The road block I’m facing is with the key derivation function. I have the same app for iOS and Android and wondering if there is a library that is accessible to iOS (swift) and Android (kotlin). My worry is that if I use different libraries for the key derivation function, I won’t be able to create the same key for both iOS and Android so the user wouldn’t be able to decrypt their data if they for example switched from using Android to iOS and vice versa. has anyone run into this issue before, and if so what library or tools did you use? Is my worry unfounded and it won’t be a problem? I’m trying to avoid using a KMS because I think that would be expensive.

Comment: I'm using [CryptLib](https://github.com/skavinvarnan/Cross-Platform-AES) for Cross platform encryption and decryption of user's data. Check it out if it helps.

Comment: @LalitFauzdar **NO**. "Support for SHA-256 for hashing the key. Never use plain text as encryption key". Yeah, you should never use SHA-256 on passwords either. People that don't know shit about security should not create cross platform crypto libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have the same app for iOS and Android and wondering if there is a library that is accessible to iOS (swift) and Android (kotlin).

PKBDF2 should be available in Java / Android and therefore Kotlin. Beware that there might be differences in handling characters in Java (LSB of `char` in Java, UTF-8 in Android).

You could also use a PBKDF that offers better security or features such as scrypt (memory hard) or Argon2, but in that case you need to use external libraries.

Regardless, passwords will never reach 128 bit security if they can be generated or remembered by the average user, so keep that in mind, *especially* for encryption where offline attacks are very possible.

> My worry is that if I use different libraries for the key derivation function, I won’t be able to create the same key for both iOS and Android so the user wouldn’t be able to decrypt their data if they for example switched from using Android to iOS and vice versa.

Your worry is partly unfounded because these functions follow a published standard, e.g. PKCS#5 in the case of PBKDF2. The only thing that can (and will) often differ is the configuration of the function. The character set encoding is one, but e.g. the internally used hash within PBKDF2 is another.

I would strongly recommend configuring PBKDF2 with the right security parameters first and then try to implement in both languages. Remember that **getting it working is not the main objective** for security. You want to use e.g. SHA-256 or better and a high iteration count. For PBKDF2 you also don't want to extract more bytes than supplied as output by the hash algorithm (e.g. 32 bytes for SHA-256).

Whatever you do, create a written protocol, point to it from the code and never use default algorithms or values: just type them out. Only the random number generation is probably best left to the runtime default.

> Is my worry unfounded and it won’t be a problem?

Partially unfounded: standardization will help, but differences in configuration may bite you.

> I’m trying to avoid using a KMS because I think that would be expensive.

You might be right, but dismissing a more secure design because of **possible** performance issues seems premature.

Comment: Thanks! This is a good answer, that makes sense. Though while thinking about this problem yesterday I thought about one other thing that could be a problem. What if a user forgets their password? If I create a separate key to encrypt/decrypt their data then encrypt that key with the derived key from their password how would password recovery be possible with this solution? Or is there another solution that I may have missed?

Comment: Well, with the current scheme you can only use the password. You could think of encrypting the data key twice: once with the password derived key and once with a public key of which you store the private key **very** securely (e.g. offline, on a separate machine, in a locker in a bunker, at an army base on the moon, audited by the president on the moon or something similar :P ). Of course, in that case, you need to inform the users that you can decrypt their data too.

Comment: Okay thank you! This has been really helpful, and I'll weight my options between this and KMS.